# Segue not passing correct value (value "stuck")

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

Alright everyone, I'm having an issue with segue passing; basically a value that is designed to change based in what's in, for example, `ViewControllerA` is not changing as it passes through to `ViewControllerB`. I'm rather lost on this problem, so please forgive that I don't know specifically what to call it.

Well, let's get to it.

I'll summarize the app structure I'm building to help you get a better idea of what exactly is going on here. I'm building an equation calculator that uses a decision-tree-network of Table VCs to pass values down, changing the options that the lower VCs display. The hierarchy is something like so:

```
// Top level:

- Main Menu View Controller (UIButton-triggered segue to calculator stack)
- ViewController (user selects type of equation out of array, it is passed into segue via indexPath.row)
- Equation View Controller (user selects individual equation, pass-thru via indexPath.row)
- DerivationViewController (discussed in detail below - source of issue)
- Calculator VC (actual calculating endpoint)

// Bottom level
```

The `DerivationViewController` essentially does the following:

```
// Declared in .h and fed by upstream VC:
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *segueInput;

// .m
@implementation DerivationViewController()
{
     NSArray* derivations;
     NSDictionary* sDict;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad:
{
     // First, the code discriminates against the fed-thru segue value to determine the options that will appear in the table
     // cells
     if (segueInput == @"Something")
     {
          derivations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Add", @"Some", @"Options", nil];
     }

     // Then, it reads into the plist. The plist consists of a dictionary of dictionaries. The plist uses segueInput to 
     // discriminate and puts the appropriate dictionary into the ivar "sDict" to allow transport across methods.
     NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
     NSDictionary * mDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     sDict = [mDict objectForKey: segueInput];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"calculation"])
    {
         // The indexPath.row then selects the appropriate number (string-encoded, i.e. @"102") to put into the downstream
         // VC's NSString* derivationNumber property.
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView3 indexPathForSelectedRow];
         CalcController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.derivationNumber = [sDict objectForKey:[derivations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```

Now here's where things don't meet up. The issue is that I noticed that no matter what derivation was selected, the units/VC settings (which are selected for by a plist in the downstream VC) are all the same. That is,

for the equation `a = b * c`, three derivations would be

```
    a = b * c
    b = a / c
    c = a / b
```

The error would show values b and c no matter what end variable was being derived for.

So I threw an NSLog on there to help me get an idea of what's going on, reading something like:

```
 NSLog(@"Forward VC reports that sDict passthrough value is: %@", [sDict objectForKey:[derivations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]);
```

To give an example, in the complete VC source there are 42 equations. Each of these equations have their derivations listed, and for equation #1 there are three derivations, so the number passed through should be 1, 2, or 3. What's happening is no matter which derivation I choose, I'm getting the number 1 coming through the segue on the terminal output from the NSLog.

And it remains the same regardless of derivation. What I'm wondering, and I'm open to consideration, is if once the first time the calculation VC is loaded, it "poisons" the value and doesn't refresh it, maintaining it across iterations, which is why the title references "releasing the View Controller". Could that be a possible issue here?

EDIT IN:

Here's the manner by which I am accessing the `derivationNumber` from within `CalcController`. I wrote this code when I was MUCH newer to Objective-C and still learning; it didn't occur to me to clean it up using a call to `[NSString intValue]` and then use `switch()`. You have been warned.

Within `-(IBAction)Calculate:(id) sender` (mapped to the Calculate UIButton):

```
if ([_derivationNumber isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    // Equation 1: 1/42:
    float a = [self.variable1.text floatValue];
    float b = [self.variable2.text floatValue];
    float ansnum = a*b;
    NSString *ans = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", ansnum];
    self.results.text = ans;
}
// etc.
```

Comment: Can you show the method in `CalcController` where you access the `derivationNumber` property?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'll edit it in in a minute. I've in the meantime been able to establish that it's some funny business occurring with `indexPath.row`. It's not a fault in the other code (the plist/code itself checks out) - the index path always returns an index of 0, and thus will always pull the first array position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest saving your selected row to a property in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and remove the segue from your cell in the storyboard if you have one as the actual selection status of the row is probably being affected by the segue.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Store the selected indexPath
    self.selectedDerivation=indexPath.row;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"calculation" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"calculation"])
    {
         // The indexPath.row then selects the appropriate number (string-encoded, i.e. @"102") to put into the downstream
         // VC's NSString* derivationNumber property.
         CalcController *destViewController = (CalcController *)segue.destinationViewController;
         destViewController.derivationNumber = [sDict objectForKey:[derivations objectAtIndex:self.selectedDerivation]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I just remove the segue and replace it? Or what should I do segue-wise?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that step. You still need the segue, but you link it from the yellow view controller icon at the bottom of your scene. Make sure you still give it the same identifier "calculation"

Comment: You can control-drag from the yellow icon in the black box below your scene to your next scene to create the segue

Comment: It looks like it'll be a good fit, except I'm getting the flag error on `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:]` reading `No visible @interface for DerivationController declares the selector performSegueWithIdentifier:`. Ideas?

Comment: You need to provide a string argument for your segue name [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier"]

Comment: It's there. I just omitted it for the purpose of the comment; but it does read `[self performSegueWithIdentifer:@"calculation"]`.

Comment: Check the spelling - I noticed there is a typo in my answer - it says identifer - so if you copied and pasted that might be your problem. I just edited it

Comment: That was one part of it. The second one was the `UIViewController` model class only declares by default the selector `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. Adding in a simple `nil` sender fixed the issue, the proper derivation results are observed on the calc stack. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to check the method signature - You should send "self" rather than nil